# How do I resolve 'NaN' and 'Undefined' errors during UI update using jQuery and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web

I keep seeing "NaN and "Undefined" whenever the UI is being updated. Also, after a minute or so, the values start updating at random intervals instead of the intervals I hard coded.

```
        temperatureInterval = setInterval(updateTemperature, 20000); // Update temperature every 20 seconds
        heartRateInterval = setInterval(updateHeartRate, 60000); // Update heart rate every 1 minute
        locationInterval = setInterval(updateLocation, 15000); // Update location every 15 seconds
      }
    }, randomTime / 10);
  });

  // Function to fetch data from the server and update the UI
  
  // Function to update the temperature in the UI
  function updateTemperature(temperature) {
    $('#body_temperature').text( temperature + " \u00B0" + "C");

    // Update temperature every 30 seconds
    setTimeout(function() {
      fetchData();
    }, 30000);
  }

  // Function to update the heart rate in the UI
  function updateHeartRate(heartRate) {
    $('#heart_rate').text(heartRate + " BPM");

    // Update heart rate every 1 minute
    setTimeout(function() {
      fetchData();
    }, 60000);
  }

  // Function to update the location in the UI
  function updateLocation(latitude, longitude) {
    const randomDeviation = (Math.random() * 2 - 1) / 10000; // Random deviation between -0.0002 and 0.0002
    const newLatitude = latitude + randomDeviation;
    const newLongitude = longitude + randomDeviation;

    $('#latitude').text(newLatitude.toFixed(6));
    $('#longitude').text(newLongitude.toFixed(6));

    // Update location every 15 seconds
    setTimeout(function() {
      updateLocation(newLatitude, newLongitude);
    }, 15000);
  }
});
```

I'm new to jQuery and Javascript and do not know how to fix this issue. I've tried Googling and using ChatGPT.

Comment: `setInterval()` doesn't pass any arguments to the function. So where do you expect `latitude` and `longitude` to come from?

Comment: FYI: `setTimeout(function() {fetchData(); , 60000)` can just be: `setTimeout(fetchData, 60000)`. And, `setTimeout(function() {fetchData();}, 30000);` can just be: `setTimeout(fetchData, 30000);`